# Can someone explain to me what is wrong with the logic

Tags: haskell

I need a function that sum all the digits as follow:
sumDigits [16,7,12,5] = 1+6+7+1+2+5 = 22

I have defined toDigits function as follow:

```hs
    toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
    toDigits n
        | n <= 0 = []
        | otherwise = toDigits(n `div` 10) ++ [n `mod` 10]
```

The sumDigits function is defined as follow:

```hs
    sumDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
    sumDigits [] = 0
    sumDigits (x:[]) = x
    sumDigits (x:zs) = (sumDigits . toDigits x) + sumDigits zs
```

The compiler shows the following errors:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a0 -> [Integer]’
              with actual type ‘[Integer]’
Possible cause: ‘toDigits’ is applied to too many arguments
  In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘toDigits x’
  In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘(sumDigits . toDigits x)’
  In the expression: (sumDigits . toDigits x) + sumDigitsX zs

Couldn't match expected type ‘a0 -> Integer’
              with actual type ‘Integer’
Possible cause: ‘sumDigitsX’ is applied to too many arguments
  In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘sumDigits zs’
  In the expression: (sumDigits . toDigits x) + sumDigits zs
  In an equation for ‘sumDigits’:
      sumDigitsX (x : zs) = (sumDigits . toDigits x) + sumDigits zs
```

I expect that toDigits will split each number to a singleton array and sumDigits will convert it to Integer. Can you explain what is wrong with this one?

Comment: `sumDigits . toDigits x` is equivalent to `sumDigits . (toDigits x)`. Is that what you intended to write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `sumDigits . toDigits x` is interpreted as `sumDigits . (toDigits x)`. Since the signature of `(.)` is [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.), the result thus should be a function, not a value.

That being said, it does not look a very good approach here:

1. you implement a lot of logic yourself, for example summing up items; and
2. the `toDigits` function runs in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* with *n* the number of digits, since you each time append, instead of prepending.

Since the order of the digits does not matter, we can implement `toDigits` as:

```
toDigits :: Integral i => i -> [i]
toDigits n | n <= 0 = []
           | otherwise = r : toDigits q
           where (q,r) = quotRem n 10
```

and we can then calculate the sum of the digits as:

```
sumDigits :: Integral i => [i] -> i
sumDigits = sum . concatMap toDigits
```

we here thus concatenate a mapping with `toDigits`, and then calculate the `sum` over that result.

This gives us the expected:

```
Prelude> sumDigits [16,7,12,5]
22
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
One question: can you clarify why toDigits runs in O(n^2)? Does it have to scan through each element of the list to append a new one there? If so, it looks more like a linked list than an array.

Comment: @KhôiHoàngNguyễn: Imagine that you have a number `123`, then you will have an expression `(([]++[1])++[2])++[3]`. `(++)` takes linear time in the length of the left operand. So the inner `(++)` function will use 0 cycles, the one above that 1 cycles, the one above that 2 cycles, etc. until `n`. A sum of 1+2+3+...+n scales O(n^2).

Comment: @KhôiHoàngNguyễn Yes, `[Integer]` is indeed a linked list type, not an array. Appending at the end with `... ++ [x]` costs O(N). A common technique is prepending instead using `x : ...` which only costs O(1). Since prepending will produce the reversed list, one can at the very end use `reverse` (cost O(N)) _once_ to put the list in the intended order. Total cost: N*O(1)+O(N)=O(N). Another efficient alternative is using "difference lists", but that's more advanced than prepending & reversing at the end.

Comment: Thank you guys. Now I understand it

Answer (score 4):

The `.` operator is function composition, and expects the expressions on each side to be functions.  When you write `(sumDigits . toDigits x)`, the left side is `sumDigits`, which is a function.  But the right side is `toDigits x`, which is not a function.  (`toDigits` is a function, but `toDigits x` is the result after that function has been applied.)

It seems that you meant `(sumDigits . toDigits) x`.  That composes the functions first, and then applies the resulting function to x, computing the sum of its digits.  In Haskell, function application has a higher precedence than anything else, so you need the parentheses to group the function composition first, and then apply it.